# How can i create a media CDN origin? I have some error

Tags: caching, cdn, live-streaming, google-cloud-cdn, google-cdn

i'm trying to use Google Media CDN and i start using example at:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/mediacdn-ls-codelab#10

I've created a google bucket with public access and after:

```
gcloud edge-cache origins create cme-origin --origin-address="gs://bucket2975"
ERROR: (gcloud.edge-cache.origins.create) NOT_FOUND: Method not found.
```

all API needed are enabled...

what's wrong?

Thanks in advance

I'm expecting same output of example:

```
Create request issued for: cme-origin
Waiting for operation [projects/my-project/locations/global/operations/operation-1612121774168-5ba3759af1919-
3fdcd7b1-99f59223] to complete...done
Created origin cme-origin
```

Comment: Getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Media CDN is still a controlled access service meaning your Google Cloud project must be allow listed in order to use the service. I suspect you are getting the error because your project hasn't been authorized as of yet. Contact your GCP Sales representative and they should be able to assist you.

Comment: Thank you, it's strange Google send me tutorial to try the service Media CDN...

Comment: Hi @juniper, did you solve this ? How did you do it ?

Comment: Media CDN [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/media-cdn/docs/overview?hl=en) is publicly available, but access to the service is restricted. Your project and portal email address needs to explicitly be allow listed by Google Cloud in order to use the new CDN service.